# Materials show up in material preview but not in render preview

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials

I creating a project in cycles, but I am having trouble with the materials. The materials show up fine in the material preview, but when I switch to render preview, some materials turn pink. How do I fix this? Thanks in advance!

[image: Material Preview] material view [image: Render Preview] render view

Comment: Are you using an HDRI image texture for your lighting in a world shader?

Answer (score 0):

Pink usually means that image texture path is lost (it requires re-linking). It might also be caused by wrong or missing Texture Coordinates mapping (material nodes)...